# How do I prevent visitors from accessing my website's API in the browser via URL?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

While I'm not new to software development, I'm relatively new to web development. I made a hobby website leveraging React and ASP.NET Core, and everything is functional (for now) and I learned quite a bit. However, I remembered that I was able to access the API from my browser, ala `www.mysite.com/api/endpoint?parameter=42`, and I've been able to access it from other devices.

There are learning materials on Pluralsight for securing one's website and/or API if said website has user accounts, but my website doesn't have user accounts since any potential users my website would have are just going to be there to look up information. How would I prevent essentially "everyone" but the frontend code for the website from making requests to the API?

Comment: You'd have some kind of authorization logic to deny the requests if it's not authorized.  In your API how do you determine if a request is authorized or not?  What criteria do you require?

Comment: There isn't a way to authenticate a "public client app" like a front-end JavaScript app. You can't know if it is the app or someone calling the API through e.g. Postman. You can however authenticate the user. And you can setup CORS rules to prevent direct usage from other JavaScript front-ends. Browsers enforce CORS rules, so that you can do. But again that doesn't prevent someone calling the API from outside a browser.

Comment: @David - I don't have anything in place to determine authorization, which is why I posted the question. I'd like it if only the website (or a really determined technical user) could access the API, instead of just having the API accessible for requests by anyone who tries the usual api url path suspects.

Comment: @jmarkman446: One approach could be something similar to XSRF protection. The site can generate a pseudo-random token when rendering the page, and the API can require that token for requests.  It doesn't validate that the user is using the page but does validate that the user requested the page before requesting the API.  Aside from that, there's really no way to authorize a request which is, by your own design, publicly accessible.